# How can I force Proguard make my illegible .XML resource file?

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-proguard

I used ProGuard in android studio to protect my data resources because I have two files in it: res / raw / fiche.xml and res / raw / fiche1 .XML so I'd make the content of my unreadable files.
My question is how to make these two files unreadable with Proguard.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProGuard only affects Java code, not resources. You will need to research other tools, like DexGuard, that may offer resource obfuscation. Whether there is a tool that *can* obfuscate `raw` resources is another matter.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, could you please take a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37314760/3287204)? Thank you ...